# Фильтр django model

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.

Не понимаю почему при передаче отфильтрованного товара, в шаблоне не наследуются его атрибуты из модели? Что я сделал не так?

models.py

```
class Good(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    price=models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=('',
    url(r'^goods'/(?P<good>\w+)\$, views.index, {'template_name': good.html}),
    ...
```

views.py

```
def index(request, template_name, good):
    args={}
    args['good']=Good.objects.filter(name=good)
    .....
    render(request, template_name, args)
```

good.html

```
{{good.name}}
{{good.price}}
```

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом примере `good` – список.
Чтобы там был один экземпляр модели, `filter` нужно заменить на `get`: `args['good']=Good.objects.get(name=good)`.

Рекомендую прочитать [документацию Джанго про то, как делать запросы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/), там много полезного.